# Taylor's theorem type of result for vector valued functions on an interval

Tags: calculus

Let $n\ge 2$, $[a,~b]$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ with $0\in[a,~b]$, and $P: [a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a function having derivatives of all orders on $[a,~b]$. Help me to prove(?) that $$P(t)=P(0)+P'(0)t+P''(0)\dfrac{t^2}{2}+g(t)t^2~~~\text{for}~t~\text{near}~0,$$
where $g(t)\rightarrow0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

Sean Dineen, in his book `Multivariate Calculus and Geometry', uses this fact while discussing the geometric significance of curvature.

Comment: Hint: use the components of the vector function

Comment: I tried, but could not get a clear picture...